# Delphi Return last 3 characters of a string

Tags: delphi, substring

I need to get the last 3 characters of a string in delphi.

I have been googling and found LastDelimiter but not an example that does something like this.

Any ideas of what I need to be looking for or how this is done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unit StrUtils contains function RightStr, which seems what you are looking for.